# How can I tell if a request is made from the local machine with Node and/or Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Some other languages has things like Request.IsLocal, is there an equivalent for Node and/or Express?

P.S. The reason I need this is because I want to use a different authentication middleware if the request is local.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.  I tried console.log(req.ip); and I got ::1 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Express comes with anything like that built in, but you can examine the value of `req.ip` and make a determination based on that.

```
if (req.ip === '127.0.0.1') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work with IPv4 and IPv6 (untested). It uses the same check that Microsoft's [System.Web.HttpRequest.IsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses - check that the request is from `127.0.0.1` or from the [IP address of the server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address). That accounts for IPv6, and if the server is bound to a specific IP address.

```
if (req.ip === '127.0.0.1' || req.ip === server.address.address) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```